# Rewriting a query

Tags: php

```
$gettmm = "SELECT min(date_format(lastupdate,'%H:%i')), max(date_format(lastupdate,'%H:%i')) FROM my_table WHERE lastupdateid='".$key1."' and date_format(lastupdate,'%Y-%m-%d')='".$search_date."'";
```

I need to change the date comparision. I prefer between as shown below.

```
and lastupdate between ('2013-08-13 00:00:00') and ('2013-08-13 23:59:59') ;
```

The variable $search_date is 2013-08-13 and I need to concat it with 00 and 23 in order to make it suitable for **between** clause. How to write the appropriate PHP code for this.

Answer (score 2):

In this case, I prefer doing this instead of using "BETWEEN"

```
and lastupdate >= '2013-08-13 and < '2013-08-14'
```

Comment: How do I programmatically generate the next date of $search_date in php?

Comment: I'm guessing you're using mysql here. But you can use the date_add function.  DATE_ADD('2012-08-13',INTERVAL 1 DAY)